# JSoup HTML parse in android

Tags: java, android, awt, jsoup

I am trying to build an app that is able to connect to a server and fill in credential in order to authenticate(like web e-mail access).
After searching a bit I found that Jsoup is suitable for such tasks.
I have searched topics on how to include the Jsoup into an android application and followed all the tips there:

1. Download the Jsoup jar file
2. Added the Jsoup jar file in the Project->Properties->Java Build paths->Libraries->Add external Jars
3. Fixed the export of the jar

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.jsoup1;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Document doc;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {

        // need http protocol
    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com").get();

         //get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),title,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

The problem is that I get a runtime error after starting the application on the phone.
It seems that dlavik cannot find some class used by the Jsoup I believe.
The java.awt package as I lokked for it seems not to be part of the android sdk, but somehow it is used by the Jsoup.
So what can I do to be able to run the application at least?

Here is the log:

```
09-17 10:53:17.134: V/ActivityThread(28297): Class path: /data/app/com.example.jsoup1-2.apk, JNI path: /data/data/com.example.jsoup1/lib
09-17 10:53:17.203: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Container;)
09-17 10:53:17.208: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Frame;)
09-17 10:53:17.209: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.awt.Frame', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.getContainingFrame
09-17 10:53:17.209: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 690 (Ljava/awt/Frame;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;
09-17 10:53:17.209: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0004
09-17 10:53:17.210: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/applet/Applet;)
09-17 10:53:17.211: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.applet.Applet', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.setAppletInstance
09-17 10:53:17.211: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 681 (Ljava/applet/Applet;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;
09-17 10:53:17.211: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x0005
09-17 10:53:17.212: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.applet.Applet', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.setAppletInstance
09-17 10:53:17.212: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 681 (Ljava/applet/Applet;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;
09-17 10:53:17.212: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000d
09-17 10:53:17.213: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Window;)
09-17 10:53:17.214: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Dialog;)
09-17 10:53:17.214: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.awt.Window', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.closeAllActiveWindows
09-17 10:53:17.215: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 697 (Ljava/awt/Window;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;
09-17 10:53:17.215: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0012
09-17 10:53:17.215: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.awt.Dialog', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.closeAllOpenDialogs
09-17 10:53:17.216: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 687 (Ljava/awt/Dialog;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;
09-17 10:53:17.216: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0012
09-17 10:53:17.216: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.applet.Applet', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.getActiveFrame
09-17 10:53:17.217: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 681 (Ljava/applet/Applet;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;
09-17 10:53:17.217: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0011
09-17 10:53:17.217: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Frame;)
09-17 10:53:17.218: I/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find method java.awt.Component.isDisplayable, referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.getActiveFrame
09-17 10:53:17.218: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5008: Ljava/awt/Component;.isDisplayable ()Z
09-17 10:53:17.219: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x005a
09-17 10:53:17.220: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/applet/Applet;)
09-17 10:53:17.220: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Window;)
09-17 10:53:17.221: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/Dialog;)
09-17 10:53:17.221: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/applet/Applet;)
09-17 10:53:17.224: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.applet.Applet', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.report
09-17 10:53:17.225: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 681 (Ljava/applet/Applet;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/PolicyRuntime;
09-17 10:53:17.225: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0033
09-17 10:53:17.226: W/dalvikvm(28297): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/BaseDialog; (687)
09-17 10:53:17.227: W/dalvikvm(28297): Link of class 'Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/BaseDialog;' failed
09-17 10:53:17.227: W/dalvikvm(28297): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/AllowDialog; (642)
09-17 10:53:17.227: W/dalvikvm(28297): Link of class 'Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/AllowDialog;' failed
09-17 10:53:17.227: I/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AllowDialog.make, referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog
09-17 10:53:17.228: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4622: Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/AllowDialog;.make (Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;I)Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/AllowDialog;
09-17 10:53:17.228: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
09-17 10:53:17.229: W/dalvikvm(28297): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/BaseDialog; (687)
09-17 10:53:17.229: W/dalvikvm(28297): Link of class 'Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/BaseDialog;' failed
09-17 10:53:17.229: W/dalvikvm(28297): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/OkDialog; (642)
09-17 10:53:17.230: W/dalvikvm(28297): Link of class 'Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/OkDialog;' failed
09-17 10:53:17.230: I/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.OkDialog.make, referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showOKDialog
09-17 10:53:17.230: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve static method 4818: Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/OkDialog;.make (Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/Session;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/OkDialog;
09-17 10:53:17.230: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0016
09-17 10:53:17.232: E/dalvikvm(28297): Could not find class 'java.applet.Applet', referenced from method com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopApplets
09-17 10:53:17.232: W/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 681 (Ljava/applet/Applet;) in Lcom/trend/iwss/jscan/runtime/PolicyRuntime;
09-17 10:53:17.232: D/dalvikvm(28297): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0018
09-17 10:53:17.235: W/dalvikvm(28297): Exception Ljava/lang/NoClassDefFoundError; thrown while initializing Lorg/jsoup/Connection$Method;
09-17 10:53:17.235: D/AndroidRuntime(28297): Shutting down VM
09-17 10:53:17.236: W/dalvikvm(28297): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4101c8a8)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Request.<init>(HttpConnection.java:313)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Request.<init>(HttpConnection.java:299)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:41)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:26)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at com.example.jsoup1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5247)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5071)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.applet.Applet
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.Session.setAppletInstance(Session.java:88)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    at org.jsoup.Connection$Method.<clinit>(Connection.java)
09-17 10:53:17.238: E/AndroidRuntime(28297):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: Hi, may I know which version of JSoup you are been using?

Comment: Hello, I am using Jsoup 1.7.2 jar

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the below code which is working good for me

```
class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                URL url= new URL("http://www.google.com");
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();
                String paragaph=doc.title();

                return Paragraph;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            System.out.println(result);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

in your onCreate()

new BackGroundTask().execute();

enable Internet permission

Comment: I have the same behavior.Could it be due to some missing parts of the sdk maybe?I have downloaded the complete IDE together with the SDK from google download page

Comment: Could you describe how you have imported the jsoup jar in your eclipse android project? I think the secret lies there.I have tried the answer from other posts but nothing worked for me

Comment: There is nothing hidden secret in this, just take the .jar file and copy it in your project's "libs" folder, no need to add it to the class path explicitly, it will get added automatically.

Comment: I have now tried with jar 1.6.1 and it works with that. I have no idea why it does not work with the 1.7.2. What version do you use?

Comment: The difference that I noticed when looking at the contents of the jars is that 1.7.2 contains also an \com\trend\iwss\jscan\runtime.Here is the Session class which uses the java.awt package that cannot be referenced by dalvik. What target sdk and API versions are you using?

Comment: target SDK 17, Android 4.2.